# How to switch or fix ppa configuration and source for Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: ppa, 19.04

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on an Acer Nitro 5 Laptop.

I am having troubles trying to install ruby and ruby on rails following the instructions on gorails.com

When running the following command:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

I get the following errors:

```
## Installing the NodeSource Node.js 8.x LTS Carbon repo...    
## Populating apt-get cache...    
+ apt-get update
Hit:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt disco-pgdg InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                  
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                        
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [88.4 kB]                      
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease                       
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                 
Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                       
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                              
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt disco-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

I have searched around and have not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) you have added do [not have files](http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu/dists/) for your Ubuntu release (19.04 or *Disco* Dingo).

So you need to remove it from the system with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
```

and then continue to follow your guide.