# Unable to boot from USB/SSD on ACER Nitro 5 AN-515-42 with Radeon RX560

Tags: boot, usb, acer, 19.04, amd-ryzen

I tried to install Ubuntu 19.04 via USB-Boot on my new notebook.
It is a new Acer Nitro 5 with its own Linux (Linpus Lite) system. But whether this already setup Linux boots nor the USB device with Ubuntu 19.04 that I just made.
The shipped system just boots into a bash like this:

```
[root@localhost /]#
```

With the bootable USB device it is a little bit different:
After choosing any option of the GRUB menu the screen sometimes just stays black with no signal of activity at all.
The other times it shows a couple of watchdog errors like described in this
[Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1786241).

I tried to edit boot options like mentioned in the answers to the bug report, but this didn't work for me. I have to add that I have no plan what exactly happens with/without those boot options. I tried to add:

> ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2

didn't work

> ro rcu_nocbs=0-7 ivrs_ioapic[4]=00:14.0 ivrs_ioapic[5]=00:00.2 quiet splash vt.handoff=1

didn't work, too

I turned off secure boot already, and the virtualization options, too.
But this also had no effect. I searched the web for two days now without finding a working solution, but I've seen posts of person who did manage to install Ubuntu on an Acer Nitro 5. Unfortunately they asked about different problems in this forum. [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138889/how-to-switch-or-fix-ppa-configuration-and-source-for-ubuntu-19-04?newreg=06b92e6f50f04fcaa7f7c255c8116a1d)

Any ideas or help?

notebook: Acer Nitro 5 AN-515-42-R9Y8
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7
GPU: AMD Radeon RX560

SOLUTION:

in GRUB menu pressing 'e' and adding

> pci=noacpi

after 'quiet splash', booting with F10 worked fine.
Solution from here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504

Comment: Some other Nitro installs: [SOLVED]Acer Nitro 5 (with Ryzen 7 2700U, RX 560X) Ubuntu 18.10  
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42

Comment: Thanks @oldfred: a simple pci=noacpi worked also for me like in the first thread you mentioned. How could I not find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Acer Nitro need pci=noacpi boot parameter. Many systems need one or several boot parameters. If nVidia nomodeset parameter required.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2413504 &

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2412117 &

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/555251/unable-to-install-ubuntu-in-my-nitro-an512-42

Most new system, even though new, need UEFI update from vendor and if a SSD firmware update to SSD.

Acer also needs "trust" setting in UEFI for ubuntu entry.
Acer Trust Settings - details, some now report that then secure boot has to be on to set trust:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947&p=13369742#post13369742 &

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 &

Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35

http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot